# Using Python Scrapy to extract XPATH in a soccer live site

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, scrapy

im trying to use Scrapy to return the results and statistics from live games in SofaScore.

Site : https://www.sofascore.com/

The code below :

```
import scrapy


class SofascoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SofaScore'
    allowed_domains = ['sofascore.com']
    start_urls = ['http://sofascore.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        time1 =
response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div").extract()
        print(time1)
        pass
```

I tried to use `response.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div").getall()` too, but it returns nothing. I used so many different xpath's and it didn't return. What im doing wrong ?

Like, today 10/06 the first match on the page is France vs Austria, xpath : /html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is generated with JavaScript, but you can get it from the API.

Open devtools in the browser and click on the `network` tab. Then click on the `live` button and look where it loads the data from. Then look at the JSON file to see its structure.

```py
import scrapy


class SofascoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SofaScore'
    allowed_domains = ['sofascore.com']
    start_urls = ['https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/football/events/live']
    custom_settings = {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.4}

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Host": "api.sofascore.com",
            "Origin": "https://www.sofascore.com",
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Referer": "https://www.sofascore.com/",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
            "Sec-GPC": "1",
            "TE": "trailers",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0], headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        events = response.json()
        events = events['events']
        # now iterate throught the list and get what you want from it
        # example:
        for event in events:
            yield {
                'event name': event['tournament']['name'],
                'time': event['time']
            }
```